# Trying to replace a set of numbers with zero in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with three columns and a lot of rows. One of the columns includes numbers like 80803 and 9995. I want to replace the specific numbers 80803 and 9995 in this column with 0.

Suppose my dataframe is called df.
I have tried to use the gsub function like gsub(80803,0,df).
But a error shows up which states `pattern has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

This is an example of what my df looks like. Just with more rows.

```
a <- c(85.42, 80.80, 78.56 , 70.40)
b <- c(110, 80803, 9995, 50)
c <- c(3, 4 , 7, 5)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
df
      a     b c
1 85.42   110 3
2 80.80 80803 4
3 78.56  9995 7
4 70.40    50 5
```

This is what i want my df to look like.

```
df
      a     b c
1 85.42   110 3
2 80.80     0 4
3 78.56     0 7
4 70.40    50 5
```

Comment: Please include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the exact error message

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this issue in base R.

```
 df$b[df$b == 80803|df$b == 9995] <- 0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can create a logical vector with `%in%` and replace those values by assigning to 0

```
df$b[df$b %in% c(80803, 9995)] <- 0
df
#      a   b c
#1 85.42 110 3
#2 80.80   0 4
#3 78.56   0 7
#4 70.40  50 5
```

NOTE: This is done in `base R` only

NOTE2: This can also take any length of vector and wouldn't have an issue if there are `NA` elements

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `replace`,

```
df$b <- replace(df$b, df$b %in% c(80803, 9995), 0)
df
#      a   b c
#1 85.42 110 3
#2 80.80   0 4
#3 78.56   0 7
#4 70.40  50 5
```